# The pre-configured props set from within the React child is overriding the custom props passed from the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

> The fontSize: 20 and color: 'red' props are displaying instead of the fontSize: 12 and color: 'blue' that is set from the Parent component, but the fontWeight: 'bold' is correctly displayed.

I have a reusable React UI child component that receives some props from its parent like so

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const BodyText = ( props ) => {
  return (
      <Text style={styles.bodyText} {...props} >{props.children}</Text>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bodyText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'red'
  },
});

export default BodyText;
```

The parent component looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import BodyText from './components/UI/BodyText'

const Parent = () => {
  return (
      <BodyText style={styles.text} >Hi There</BodyText>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
});

export default Parent;
```

Interestingly when I play around in [CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-sky-iq2vy?file=/src/App.js), it is displaying correctly but not on my local setup.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your `BodyText.js` like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const BodyText = (props) => {
  const { style, children, ...rest } = props;   // Destructure props here...

  return (
    <Text style={[styles.bodyText, style]} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bodyText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'red',
  },
});

export default BodyText;
```

[Working Example Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/props-example)

Comment: Thank you for helping. It is a 100% valid code and should work but unfortunately, I am still not getting the desired output. No change from before. I console logged the props.style and strangely it is rending the correct object with the props initially and then in the last render, it renders an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default props as well:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const BodyText = ( props ) => {
  return (
      <Text style={{
                fontSize: props.fontSize,
                color: props.color
                }}>
             {props.children}</Text>
  );
};

BodyText.defaultProps = {
   fontSize:20,
   color:'red'
}

export default BodyText;
```

After you can use you component with new props or not:

```js
 <BodyText fontSize={12} color='blue'>Hi There</BodyText>
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah this should work but it doesn't in my case. I console logged props and it is rendering an empty object in the last render. Funny thing is it is setting the other styles correctly.

Comment: Did you check the Snack that I provided

Comment: @KartikeyVaish Yes, I did and it is working. As I said before your code it valid and it should work and I think even my code should work. When I test it in my local system nothing is working. Some strange issue I cannot wrap my head around it.